# Prove that $X$ is complete but not inner product, and vice versa

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be the space $C[0, 1]$ under the norm $||·||_{p}$ for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$.

(a) Show that $X$ is complete for $p = \infty$, but it is then not an inner product space.

(b) Show that $X$ is an inner product space for $p = 2$, but it is then not complete.

I thought about this problem for a while, but still got nowhere. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 4):

1. The fact that $(C[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{L^\infty})$ is complete follows from the triangle inequality estimate $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)-f_n(y)| + |f_n(y)-f(y)|$.
2. The fact that $(C[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{L^\infty})$ does not have a compatible inner product can be checked by demonstrating that the parallelogram law is not satisfied. One way to do this is to consider two functions $f,g$ whose supports are disjoint. This example actually shows two interesting geometric properties of inner product spaces. First, we can only have $\| x + y \| = \| x - y \|$ if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. Second, because of the Pythagorean theorem, we can only have $\| x \| = \| x + y \| = \| x - y \|$ if $y=0$.
3. The fact that $(C[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{L^2})$ has a compatible inner product is easy enough to check. The only difficulty is showing that any nonzero continuous function has nonzero square integral, but this can be done by showing that if a continuous function is not zero at a point then it is not zero on an interval around the point.
4. The fact that $(C[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{L^2}$ is not complete can be shown by considering a sequence of bounded continuous functions which converge pointwise to a discontinuous function. The boundedness allows the application of the dominated convergence theorem, which ensures the convergence in the sense of $L^2$. To be precise here, we actually need a limit which has no continuous representative in $L^2$. For example, $f_n(x)=x^n$ actually converges in the sense of $L^2$ to the zero function, even though this is not the pointwise limit, so this does not furnish a counterexample. A sequence whose pointwise limit is the indicator function of $[1/2,1]$ would work, however.

Clarifications:

1. If $f_n$ are continuous and Cauchy in $L^\infty$, then by the completeness of the real numbers, there exists $f$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Now you need to show that $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty$ and that $f$ is continuous. Given that $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty$ (which I won't show here), we can conclude that $f$ is continuous by using the inequality above. In particular we need the uniformity to be able to choose the same $n$ at both $x$ and $y$.
2. If $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm induced by an inner product, then we have the parallelogram law, $2 \| x \|^2 + 2 \| y \|^2 = \| x + y \|^2 + \| x - y \|^2$. Now suppose $f$ and $g$ have disjoint supports. Then $\| f + g \|_{L^\infty} = \| f - g \|_{L^\infty} = \max \left \{ \| f \|_{L^\infty}, \| g \|_{L^\infty} \right \}$. Check that this contradicts the parallelogram law.
3. You should already know that $\| \cdot \|_{L^2}$ is induced by $(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx$. So all you need to show is that this map is an inner product. Bilinearity is easy to check using properties of the integral. So the only issue is positive definiteness. So suppose $f$ is not identically zero, then there are $x,\varepsilon$ such that $f(x)^2 > \varepsilon$, which means there is an interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, in which $f(y)^2 > \varepsilon/2$. So $\| f \|_{L^2} > (\varepsilon/2)(2 \delta) = \varepsilon \delta > 0$. Finally $\| 0 \|_{L^2} = 0$ is trivial.
4. To find a sequence of continuous functions which converge to the indicator function of $[1/2,1]$, consider functions $f_n$ which are $0$ on $[0,1/2-1/2n]$, $1$ on $[1/2+1/2n,1]$, and increase linearly from $0$ to $1$ on $[1/2-1/2n,1/2+1/2n]$. If you have the dominated convergence theorem, then the convergence desired here is an easy consequence. If you don't, you can do everything explicitly in this simple case and wind up just dealing with a limit of real numbers.

It remains to show that there is no continuous function which is equal almost everywhere to this indicator function. For this, if $g$ is equal a.e. to this indicator function, then for any $\delta > 0$ we have $x \in (1/2-\delta,1/2)$ with $g(x)=0$ and $y \in (1/2,1/2+\delta)$ with $g(y)=1$. (Why?) Such a $g$ can't be continuous at $1/2$ because its left and right limits disagree there or fail to exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed insights, Ian! But they overblow my head, probably because my background is too weak now, so can you please elaborate each point in detailed?

Comment: @user177196 I added some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

For part a) we want to show that if some sequence is Cauchy then it converges. We will do this in two steps: first we will show that our sequence is bounded; then we will say that our sequence is really just a bounded sequence of real numbers and invoke that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence to show the completeness of $C([0,1])$.

So take some sequence $f_k \in C([0,1])$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Suppose that our sequence is Cauchy which is to say that there exists some big $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m \ge N$ then:
$$\sup \limits_{x \in[0,1]}|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \varepsilon.$$
Now the supremum is the biggest the distance could be so we may write:
$$|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \varepsilon,$$
$$f_m - \varepsilon < f_n < f_m + \varepsilon.$$

We know that $f_k$ is continuous for all $k$. Furthermore a continuous function on a bounded interval is itself bounded. Writing this in symbols we have that $|f_k| < B_k$ for some large bound $B_k$. Thus in particular, taking $k=m$ we can say:
$$-B_m < f_m < B_m$$
and so therefore we have bounded our sequence as:
$$f_m - \varepsilon < f_n < f_m + \varepsilon,$$
$$-B_m - \varepsilon < f_n < B_m + \varepsilon,$$
$$|f_n| < B_m + \varepsilon.$$
Thus,
$$\sup |f_n| < B_m + \varepsilon.$$

So from the above we can say that $|f_n(x)| < B$ for some $B$. In particular fix $x_0$ then the real sequence $f_n(x_0)$ is bounded and it is also Cauchy by hypothesis and so it must converge to some limit call it $f(x_0)$. Thus we have found that for all $x_0$ there must exist an $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we have $|f_n(x_0) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$.

Now $$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le  |f_n(x) - f_N(x)| + |f_N(x) - f(x)|$$

We know that we can make both of the right hand terms small so that:

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le  |f_n(x) - f_N(x)| + |f_N(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$
Thus, 
$$\sup|f_n - f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$

Lastly we have to check that the function $f(x)$ is continuous, otherwise $C([0,1])$ wouldn't be complete.
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)|$$
As each $f_n$ is continuous we can make the middle term small by taking $|x-y| < \delta$ and the other two terms can be made small as $f$ is the pointwise limit of $f_n$. Thus $f(x) \in C([0,1])$.

To show the space is not complete you can try the sequence of continuous functions:
$$f_n(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c c}1 & 0 \le x \le 1/2 - 1/n\\
-nx + n/2 &1/2- 1/n \le x \le 1/2 + 1/n\\
-1 & 1/2 + 1/n \le x \le 1 \end{array} \right.$$
Check that this sequence is Cauchy and then show it doesn't converge in $C([0,1])$.

If you draw this function it makes more sense and you will see that what is happening is that you have a continuous function for each $n$ but in the limit as $n$ goes to infinity it becomes discontinuous.

Comment: Great work, Ben! I love how detailed your solutions are, but I have two questions: How do we know there is a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$? And how does showing <x,y> in a specific form being an inner product can generalize that X is an inner product space for $p=2$? I'm sorry, but my background is probably too weak to not ask these questions:P

Comment: @user177196 for your first question. We are to show that the space is complete. This means that we have to prove $\textbf {if} $ a sequence is cauchy then it is also convergent. The whole point is we are proving if we have such a cauchy sequence then it converges.

For your second to show $X$ is an inner product space we just need to find $\textbf{any}$ inner product on $X$. In the case of the $p=2$ norm we can build such an inner product in the way I described. AS we find one inner product we can say that the space itself is as required.

Comment: :thank you very much for your clear explanation! I got most of your proof now, but I can't prove that $f_{n}(x)$ doesn't converge in $C([0,1])$. Can you please elaborate on it with a proof? The picture is clear that as $n ->\infty$, the function is discontinuous at the point $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Shouldn't we consider the set $$\{|f_n| : n \in \mathbb{N}\},$$ since sup here is part of the distance's definition?

Comment: @user177196 you can show it doesn't converge in $C([0,1])$ by showing that it converges to the discontinuous function $f$ such that $f(x) = -1$ for $0 \le x \le 1/2$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $1/2 < x \le 1$. 

As for considering the set I'm not sure what you mean. Define $a_n = \sup|f_n|$. Then $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded set of real numbers and so there is a convergent, in the usual sense, subsequence $a_{n_k} \to L$ as $k \to \infty$ say. Saying this is the same as saying for large $k$ that $|a_{n_k} - L| < \varepsilon$, which is all we need from using that set.

Comment: thank you for your patience. I meant, when we want to prove $f_{n} -> L$, it is equivalent to prove that $lim_{n->infty} d(f_{n},L)= 0$, where $d(x,y)=sup_{x\in [0,1]}|x-y|$. So the set I think we should consider is only $${|f_{n}|: n\in N}$$ because only then the rest of your proof follows nicely. If you meant to consider the set $${sup{|f_{n}|}: n\in N}$$ and show that it converges, it means we need to show $lim_{n->infty} d(sup{|f_{n}|},L)= 0$, so things will be a bit different.

Comment: I meant $d(f_n,f_m)= sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_{n}(x)-f_m(x)|$. Sorry for my typo above.

Comment: @user177196 Yes you are right I have edited my answer. Sorry for the confusion :-)

Comment: Beautiful work for part (a) now, Ben! I missed the continuity part:P May you please help with part (b) as well, since Ian's explanation, despite his great effort to help me, which I really appreciate, is still too dense for me to follow:( You